# RecyclerView new row not display even after notifyItemInserted called

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I tried many ways but couldn't get `RecyclerView` display new rows.

This is my adapter:

```
private inner class MyAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder>() {

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        LogDog.i(TAG, "getItemCount=" + _to.size)
        return _to.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder?, position: Int) {
        LogDog.i(TAG, "Binding row $position of size=" + _to.size)
        val contactId = _to[position]
        holder?._tv_name?.text = DB.getString(TblContact, TblContact._display, contactId)
        holder?._tv_address?.text = DB.getString(TblContact, TblContact._address, contactId)
        holder?._position = position
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        LogDog.i(TAG, "onCreateViewHolder, size=" + _to.size)
        return MyViewHolder(activity.layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.r_to, parent, false))
    }

}
```

When contact `button` clicked, contact dialog displays to select and calls `_adListener` to add row:

```
private val _to = ArrayList<Long>()
private var _adapter = MyAdapter()

private val _addListener : (Long) -> Unit = { id ->
    _to.add(id)
    Log.i(TAG, "_addListener size=" + _to.size)
    //_adapter.notifyItemInserted(_to.size - 1)
    _adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
}

private val _addClicker = View.OnClickListener { _ ->
    DlgContactEdit(activity, null, null, _addListener).show()
}

private val _lookupClicker = View.OnClickListener { _ ->
    DlgContactSelector(activity, _addListener).show()
}
```

From log, I do see `_addListener` is called, but new rows not displaying! Only when layout refreshes (e.g., keyboard displays and hides), new rows will display to the real content in `_to` list. What could be the reason?

I also tried to use Handler to call `notifyItemInserted` later, or change to `notifyDataSetChanged`, but no luck.

Comment: can you post your full code for setting recyclerview

Comment: underscores everywhere... you should read https://github.com/android/kotlin-guides

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for my stupid error. Just noticed I didn't use _adapter at all, I was writing this

```
rv_to.adapter = MyAdapter()
```

which is completely wrong.

And it works without calling invalidate.

Thanks all for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to many tutorials, notifyChange does not work by itself, most importantly you need to refresh the recycler view .invalidate().
Here is an example of a function i have in one of my classes that can call from different places to refresh my RV.

```
/**
 * Sets up the recycler view and refreshes it after data changes
 */
private void setUpView() {
    Schedule_AddTimes_Adapter adapter = new Schedule_AddTimes_Adapter(mTimesList);
    RecyclerView.ItemDecoration divider = new DividerItemDecoration(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.divider));
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext);
    mDoseTimesList.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    mDoseTimesList.setAdapter(adapter);
    mDoseTimesList.addItemDecoration(divider);
    mDoseTimesList.invalidate();
}
```

Comment: `notifyDataSetChanged()`  works everywhere. I'm not sure what kind of code you're using, but I've used that method hundreds of times, and I've never had it fail to refresh my RecyclerView. I usually prefer to use something more specific like `notifyItemInserted()` because it doesn't redraw my whole list.